# validating textbox in a for loop

Tags: php

I have a textbox that is in a `for` loop. I want to validate this textbox if no data is entered then it should display an error message.

```
  <form method="post" action="test.php">
     <?php for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) { ?>                
        <input type='text' name='txtName[]' required />                                               
    <?php } ?>  
    <input type="submit" name="btnConfirm" value="Proceed" class="button" /> 
  </form>


<?php
    $name = $_POST['txtName'];

    if(isset($_POST['btnConfirm'])) {
       if(!empty($name))  { echo "it worked!"; } 
       else { echo "Please enter your name."; }
    }
?>
```

It works when I use this code:

```
$name = $_POST['txtName[]'];
```

but after I enter data in `textbox`, it doesn't go to my `else` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type='text' name='txtName[]' />
```

And

```
$name = $_POST['txtName'];

if(isset($_POST['btnConfirm'])) {
$flag=true;
  for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
   if(empty($name[$i]))  $flag=false;
}
if($flag) echo "it worked!"; 
   else  echo "Please enter your name.";
```